# Async function returns empty array

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to create a matrix of some pairs of data. `fetchDataPair()` is an `async` function.

```
async function fetchData(info_array){
    let matrix = []
    for(const i of info_array){
        let row = []
        for (const j of info_array){
            if (i != j){
                let pair = fetchDataPair(i,j)
                row.push(pair)
            }else{
                row.push(null)
            }
        }
        Promise.all(row).then((resolvedRow)=>{ //resolve all the promises in the row, then push to matrix
            matrix.push(resolvedRow)
        })
    }
    //matrix should be an array of arrays of (resolved) promises, but it just returns an empty array
    console.log(matrix) //logs []
    return matrix
}
```

This code unfortunately seems to reach `return matrix` before the rows are pushed into the array, but I can't understand why.

Thanks

EDIT: Fixed the name of the inside function from `fetchData` to `fetchDataPair`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `//resolve all the promises in the row, then push to matrix`

That has exactly the same problem as would waiting for the `pair` promise resolve and pushing its result to the `row` array afterwards - you can't do that, you need to create an array of promises and use `Promise.all`:

```
function fetchData(info_array) {
    let matrix = []
    for (const i of info_array) {
        let row = []
        for (const j of info_array) {
            if (i != j) {
                let pair = fetchDataPair(i,j)
                row.push(pair)
            } else {
                row.push(null)
            }
        }
        matrix.push(Promise.all(row))
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^
    }
    return Promise.all(matrix)
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: By the way I have one question. My goal is to fetch each `pair` asynchronously, but I have this doubt: Is this fetching each pair on a row asynchronously, then waiting until it gets resolved, and then continuing with the next row? Or is it also doing all the rows asynchronously? Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity: `else { row.push(null) }` is unnecessary, isn't it?

Comment: @LeonBrasero This is fetching all pairs concurrently, then waiting for all results. If you want the fetches to be sequential, use `await` in the loop.

Comment: @pzaenger No, it's necessary, to ensure that the diagonal of the matrix is filled with `null` values. If you omitted it, every row would be one item short.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple mistakes in the code.
The problem is that you need to wait on Promise.all. If you use .then you are subscribing to be notified when it is finished but the execution continues and the console is printed before the promise finishes the execution.

```
async function fetchData(info_array){
    let matrix = [];
    for(const i of info_array){
        let row = []
        for (const j of info_array){
            if (i != j){
                let pair = fetchData(i,j)
                row.push(pair)
            }
            else {
                row.push(null);
            }
        }

        const rowProc = await Promise.all(row);
        matrix.push(rowProc);
    }
    
    console.log(matrix)
    return matrix
}
```

Comment: This no longer returns a matrix but a flat array, though